# Make ajax call controller in current catalog/project instead of root catalog

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have a project , lets name it App1. On the webserver, i have created another application, inside "App1", lets name it App2.
Problem is that inside App2, i am calling "RegisterData" method, but it is looking in App1 folders HomeController and not in App2's HomeController and therefore throwing exception that RegisterData is not found in App1. How do i make it look in the current folder / project Homecontroller instead of root ?

```
 $.ajax({
             async: "false",
             url: 'Home/RegisterData/',
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
             success: function (response) {

             },
             error: function (response) {

             }
         });
```

Comment: You need to convert the url with Url.Content http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Url.Content instead and that solved the problem.